# How to extract a particular word/Numeric Value from Object dtype?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to automate something for my firm using python(irrelevant) and here lies my problem.
First of all i am creating a dataframe from a particular folder in my mailbox.(No Problem till here)"

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 36 entries, 0 to 35
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   Unnamed: 0     36 non-null     int64         
 1   Date           36 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 2   Subject        36 non-null     object        
 3   Sender         36 non-null     object        
 4   Body           36 non-null     object        
 5   OpportunityID  36 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 1.8+ KB
```

Body column contains email trails (which are quiet long); however all of them contain 2 essential pieces of information i am concerned with :

1. Each email body contains an "Opportunity ID : 12345678(exactly 8 letter length)"
2. One of the word from the following choices : `Won/won/Lost/lost/Active/active/Hold/hold`

I want to be able to extract these two pieces of information from the Body column to 2 separate columns.

Body Column is not converting to string no matter WHAT i try. Moreover, I have tried regular expressions, str.split, extract, re, encoding to utf-8.
Nothing seems to work. using `re.findall(r"\d+",df.Body)` gives : 
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Example of Body Column :
Dear XX,

Unfortunately, we’ve ***lost*** this one.

Best regards

XXX

From: XXXX 
Sent: Wednesday, April 15, 2020 4:46 PM
To: XXX
Cc:XXX
Subject: Reminder to update X

We are in process of cleaning up the pipeline and require you to please provide a status update on the below opportunity.

Please indicate if it is Active/ Won / Lost or Cancelled

Details Below :

- ***Opportunity ID: 12345678***
- Name of the Client :X
- Opportunity Description : X
- Engagement Partner : X
- Engagement Manager : X
- Gross Fees SAR : 1033000
- Gross Fees USD m :

Let me know if you have any concerns. 
X

Comment: what is the type of Body values ? Are they JSON strings?, or strings only ? If they're long strings, can you provide an example (or some), we currently do not know how the parse can be done without knowing the values.

Comment: Ok, try `df['Opportunity_ID']=df['Body'].str.extract(r'Opportunity\s+ID\s*:\s*(\d{8})')` and `df['Keyword']=df['Body'].str.extract(r'(?i)\b(won|lost|active|hold)\b')` and print `df`

Comment: added description of body column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Opportunity_ID']=df['Body'].str.extract(r'Opportunity\s+ID\s*:\s*(\d{8})') 
df['Keyword']=df['Body'].str.extract(r'(?i)\b(won|lost|active|hold)\b')
```

The first `Opportunity\s+ID\s*:\s*(\d{8})` regex matches `Opportunity`, one or more whitespaces (with `\s+`), an `ID` substring, a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars (see `\s*:\s*`) and then *captures* into Group 1 any eight digits (see `(\d{8})`).

The `r'(?i)\b(won|lost|active|hold)\b'` pattern just matches any of the four alternatives in a capturing groups (joined with the help of `|` alternation operator) as whole words (`\b` are word boundaries) in a case insensitive way (see the `(?i)` modifier).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Had been struggling with re for the past 6 hours !!